# PEBS sampling from kernel module

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, profiling, intel, perf

I want to enable Intel's PEBS sampling from a loadable kernel module and handle some cases in the PEBS handler from that kernel module. I know that I can use PAPI from user space, but I'm not sure how I can enable PEBS sampling and register a handler in kernel space. How would I write code to do this?

Comment: Well the `perf` tool has had in-kernel support for PEBS for a while, so you could take a peek at that code.

Comment: From the kernel code, PEBS interrupts are handled by perf_event_nmi_ha
ndler which eventually calls x86_pmu_handle_irq. Is there any way I can register an additional call back function from my custom kernel module without replacing the original handler?

Comment: Additionally, I don't want to patch the kernel.